# Socket.io error in sending arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, socket.io

I have 3 variables to send to the client using socket.io, namely, `mapRes` & `location`.

`server.js`

```
var mapRes = {width : 720, height: 1040};
var location = [{x:100,y:100,z:100},{x:200,y:200,z:200}];
var obj = {'1':{x:100,y:200}}, '2':{x:200,y:100}};
io.on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.emit("mapRes",mapRes);
    socket.emit("location",location);
    socket.emit("object",obj);
}
```

`client.html`

```
socket.on('mapRes',function(message){
    var mapRes = message;
    console.log(mapRes);
});
socket.on('location',function(message){
    var location = message;
    console.log(location);
});
socket.on('object',function (message){
    var object = message;
    console.log (object);
});
```

At the client side (browser), the first variable `mapRes` is received as expected.

`Object { width: 720, height: 1040 }`

The second variable, however, is received as shown below:

`Array [ Object, Object]`

The third object is received as below:

`Object { 1: Object, 2: Object}`

Is there a way to receive these variables/objects properly?

Comment: Are you sure, the object hasn't been sent? Assuming you're using firefox, its console sometimes displays objects weirdly (in a collapsed way). Try logging e.g. message[0].x or clicking on the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has been sent correctly, you're just not seeing the whole object.

This is due to Firefox collapsing objects when logged to console:

[image: firefox console]

If you click on the underlined object, the right panel should open and show you more details about the object.